# problem with including external library

Tags: 7, theming

Below I check for file existence and its exists.

```
$path = libraries_get_path('nusoap') . '/nusoap.php';
if(file_exists($path)) {
    print file_get_contents($path);
    die;
}
```

But when I try to include it I get `500 Internal server error`.

```
$path = libraries_get_path('nusoap') . '/nusoap.php';
if(file_exists($path)) {
    require_once $path;
}
```

Owner and Group of all files are www-data

**EDIT**

```
[Mon Dec 24 12:59:12 2012] [error] [client 2.146.17.144] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class XMLSchema in /sites/all/modules/fedora_store/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 2049, referer: http://127.0.0.1/fedora/store/transaction/2/mellat
```

Comment: Please, look through your web server logs. For Apache `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or something like that.  
«Owner and Group of all files are www-data» — please take a look at these documents: http://drupal.org/node/244924, http://www.lullabot.com/articles/keeping-drupals-files-safe

Comment: The problem was with your nusoap.php script?

Comment: Yes, try to redeclare class XMLSchema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get fatal web server/PHP error it is very useful to check the logs. Usually Apache logs are placed in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` but it may differ.

> Owner and Group of all files are www-data

I must warn you that *www-data* should not be an owner for most PHP files. *www-data* usually needs only read permissions. But it is not directly related to this question.